# Is it a good practice to avoid ad hoc sql altogether in ASP.NET applications?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, database-design, stored-procedures

Instead create only stored procedures and call them from from the code?

Comment: I think you mean ['ad hoc'](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/05/stored-procedures-vs-ad-hoc-sql.html) rather than ['dynamic'](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a place for dynamic SQL and/or ad hoc SQL, but it needs to be justified based on the particular usage needs.

Stored procedures are by far a best practice for almost all situations and should be strongly considered first.

This issue is a little bigger than just procs or ad hoc, because the database has a wide variety of tools to define its interface, including tables, views, functions and procedures.

People here have mentioned the execution plans and parameterization but, by far, the most important thing in my mind is that any technique which relies on exposed base tables to users means that you lose any ability for the database to change its underlying implementation or control security vertically or horizontally.  At the very least, I would expose only views to a typical application/user/role.

In a scenario where the application or user's account only has access to EXEC SPs, then there is no possibility of that account being able to even have a hope of using a SQL injection of the form: "; SELECT name, password from USERS;" or "; DELETE FROM USERS;" or "; DROP TABLE USERS;" because the account doesn't have anything but EXEC (and certainly no DDL).  You can control column visibility at the SP level and not have to deny select on an employee salary column, for example.

In other words, unless you are comfortable granting db_datareader to public (because that's effectively what you are doing when you LINQ-to-tables), then you need some sort of realistic security in your application, and SPs are the only way to go, with LINQ-to-views possibly being acceptable.

Comment: @Gabe QBE can be done with SPs even without dynamic or ad hoc SQL, but there are always cases where dynamic or ad hoc SQL (parametrized or not) can be effective.  I'm saying that you give up a lot of security and maintainability by exposing your table design to consumers instead of exposing a smaller and well-defined surface area of your database.  Just like you might do in any OO design, or any programming paradigm, really.

Comment: I realize it can be done, I'm asking how you would do it. If you have a table with 10 fields (each with a value, operator, and sort order), would you make an SP with 30 parameters and have the SP generate a query?

Comment: @Gabe Probably with a non-updatable view and give access to the application account, so new columns could be added to the view without having to update an SP and the client app could offer the QBE options dynamically. SP is good approach, particularly if you want to add index hints (which only the database should know about) if the query can get bad performance. This also lets you tune underneath. I think the more large/complex the underlying data and more likelihood for widely varying good execution plans, the more likelihood for bringing it inside db perimeter to ensure availability.

Comment: I would dispute sprocs as always best practice on your security basis. Dynamically generated SQL and SQL built directly from user input are not the same thing. Most ORMs (including Linq) dynamically generate SQL statements, and an ad-hoc query as a string in your code does not expose a security risk.

Comment: It is *always* best practice to parametrise user input and *never* let user input text get added to a SQL statement. Sprocs are sometimes (but not always) best practice - mainly when the value of marginally better cached query plans or a need to lock down your application's access to very narrow actions outweighs their much higher maintenance cost (in splitting data access code across DB and application and needing both a DDL statement and a recompile in order to make any change)

Comment: @Keith It depends upon your overall security model. I would generally not expose tables to any accounts of general users, hence ORMs which do LINQ-to-tables are out. I find that a better locked down interface to the database generally decreases maintenance costs, since the interface to the database is controlled and well defined and easily inventoried by the exposed surface are interface and not just every table and every column and who knows who's using it.

Comment: @Keith But I treat the database as any other OO component of my system.  Well-defined interface, division of responsibilities, separation of concerns, etc.  I don't see how often the same people who treat their OO segregation seriously like to have a huge database surface area.

Answer (score 4):

Depends entirely on what you're doing.

As a general rule a stored proc will have it's query plan cached better than a dynamically generated SQL statement. It will also be slightly easier to maintain indexes for.

However, dynamically generated SQL statements can have their query plans cached, so the difference is marginal.

Dynamically generated SQL statement can also introduce security risk - always parameterise them.

That said sprocs are a pain to maintain and update, they separate DB-logic and .Net code in a way that makes it harder for developers to piece together what a data access method is doing.

Also, to fix or update a SQL string you just change code. To fix or update a sproc you have to change the database - often a much messier option.

So I wouldn't recommend that as a 'one size fits all' best practice.

Answer (score 2):

There is no right or wrong answer here.  There are benefits to both which can be easily obtained through a google search.  Different projects with different requirements may lead you to different solutions.  It's not as black or white as you might want it to be.  You might as well throw ORMs into the mix.  If you prefer sql queries in your data layer as opposed to stored procs, make sure you use parametrized queries.

Answer (score 1):

sql in sp- easy to maintain, sql in app- pain in the butt ot maintain.

it's so much faster and easier to hop onto a sql instance, modify an sp, test it, then deploy the sp, instead of having to modify the code in the app, test it, then deploy the app.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the data distribution in your table. Prepared query plans and stored procedures get cached, and the plan itself depends on the table statistics.

Suppose you've building a blog and that your posts table has a user_id. And that you're frequently doing stuff like:

```
select posts.* from posts where user_id = ? order by published desc limit 20;
```

Suppose indexes on posts (user_id) and posts (published desc).

Additionally suppose that you've two authors, author1 which wrote 3 posts a long time ago, and author2 who has written 10k posts since.

In this case, the query plan of the ad hoc query will be very different depending on whether you're fetching the author1 posts or the author2 posts:

- For author1, the database will decide to use the index on user_id and sort the results.
- For author2, the database will read the first 20 rows using the index on published.

If you prepare the statement, the planner will pick either of the two. Suppose the second (which I think is likely): applied to author1, this means going through the whole table by way of the index -- which is much slower than the optimal plan.

Answer (score 0):

If simplicity is your goal, then an ORM would be a good practice for your simple database operations

ORMs like Entity Framework, nHibernate, LINQ to SQL, etc. will manage the code creation of the data access and repository layers and provide you with strongly typed objects representing your tables.  This can lead to a cleaner, more maintainable architecture.

Save the stored procedures for your more complex queries.  This is where you can take advantage of advanced SQL and cached query plans.

Answer (score -2):

1. Dynamic SQL - Bad
2. Stored Procedures - Better
3. Linq-To-SQL or Linq-to-EF (or ORM tools) - Best

You do not want dynamic SQL inside your application since you do not have compile-time checking.  Stored procedures will at least be checked, but it is still not part of a cohesive usnit and removes business logic to the database layer.  Linq-To-EF will allow business logic to stay inside your application and allow you to have compile-time checking of syntax.

Comment: Most ORM tools, including Linq, will result in ad-hoc runtime generated SQL code. If it was standard best practice to always use sprocs Linq would be bad practice.

Comment: @Keith - that was one of my reasons to be against Linq-To-Sql until some of the other software engineers did a study and found out that Linq generated SQL will also be cached.  It took a while to convince me, but I finally saw the proof.  Good comment.

Comment: I would rather have parameterised SQL in my code than to use Stored Procedures. Linq2Sql entities maps fine to SQL code executed on the DbContext. (used when there is no equivalent in Linq)

Comment: ORM tools are often the worst possible way to generate code that will perform well. They have their place but should NOT be the considered the best way.